# Command failing for DynamoDB table replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am attempting to run the command

```
aws dynamodb update-table \
--table-name DeletedIdentifier \
--region us-west-2 \
--replica-updates '[{"Create": {"RegionName": "eu-north-1", "ProvisionedThroughputOverride": {"ReadCapacityUnits": "2000000"}}}]'
```

To replicate a non-global table between regions in DDB. However, this is producing the error

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateTable operation: Failed to perform action due to insufficient TableMaxReadCapacityUnits limits in eu-north-1. Current limit is 2000000 RCU. Requested amount for table or GSI is 5000000 RCU. Please contact https://aws.amazon.com/support for limit change.
```

This appears odd because the command **is** requesting only 2000000 RCUs. However, the default value for the original table is 5000000 RCUs. Why is the `ProvisionedThroughputOverride` not being applied?

I have looked into [the documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/dynamodb/update-table.html) for alternate parameters to run, but have not yet found any alternatives for the ReadCapacityUnits argument

Answer (score 0):

With global tables you must ensure all of your regions capacity limits are aligned. You can check the limits per region by calling the `describe-limits` API and request to have them updated using Service Quotas.

Comment: Thanks, that is unfortunate. So then, what purpose does `ProvisionedThroughPutOverride` serve? Since the values need to match between regions no matter what

Comment: Not the values of your tables capacity, the values of your regions/tables limits.